# function is marked #[no_mangle], but not exported

Tags: rust

I have a project with two files:

- `src/lib.rs`
- `src/rle.rs`

`rle.rs` contains the following (and much more):

```
extern crate libc;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Rle {
    pub lengths: Vec<i32>,
    pub values: Vec<i32>,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rle_new(blablabla...)
```

`lib.rs` looks like the following:

```
mod rle;
use rle::rle_new; 
// blablabla
```

When I load the library in Python I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compact_ranges.py", line 19, in <module>
    lib.rle_new.restype = POINTER(RleS)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 378, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 383, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7f94ca700370, rle_new): symbol not found
```

It seems like Rust understands this (clever, clever) because my linter says:

```
17   1 warning         function rle_new is marked #[no_mangle], but not exported, #[warn(private_no_mangle_fns)] on by default (rust-cargo)
```

How do I fix this and make my function `rle_new` available from the target/debug/libranges.dylib file?

The `crate-type` in my `Cargo.toml` is `["dylib"]`

Comment: Shot in the dark: `pub use rle::rle_new;` in `lib.rs`? (`rle` is not `pub`...)

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I also tried to change `mod rle` to `pub mod rle` but that did not work either. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Might want to open a bug to improve the warning; it would be so more useful if it included a tip on how to fix this :(

Comment: Well, the easiest way was to move my `rle_new` function to the `lib.rs` file. Worked then :) Keeping this open as is, in case sb has an answer.

Comment: Doing as @MatthieuM. suggests (`pub use`) makes `_rle_new` show up as an exported symbol in the library according to `nm`. Works for me.

Comment: Okay, so it adds a prefix `_` to `rle_new` then? Anyways, thanks for the tip, I must have made a mistake. If you add that as an answer I will accept it Matthieu M:)

Comment: @Shepmaster: With a leading `_` as prefix? If it's the case I would let you answer and fill in the blanks, seems weird that the symbol name would be altered...

Comment: using `pub use rle::rle_new` I get a `rle_new` symbol in `./target/debug/<lib>.so`, so I cannot reproduce the leading `_`

Comment: @Neikos that's a platform difference. macOS vs Linux.

Comment: Ah okay, TIL! Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Rust philosophy is to prefer explicit over implicit.

Rust will only export symbols that are publicly accessible from the root crate. This makes it very easy to inspect the public interface of a crate without crawling through all files: just follow the `pub` from the root.

In your case, the symbol `rle_new` is publicly accessible to anyone having access to the `rle` module (such as sibling modules), but the `rle` module itself is not publicly accessible in the root crate.

The simplest solution is to selectively export this symbol:

```
pub use rle::rle_new;
```